# Difference between <type 'classobj'>, <type 'object'>?

Tags: python, python-2.7

According to [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> The `__mro__` attribute of the type lists the method resolution search
>   order used by both `getattr()` and `super()`. The attribute is dynamic and
>   can change whenever the inheritance hierarchy is updated.

I tried the `__mro__` attribute with this:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testValue = 123
```

Then I typed:

```
type(a).__mro__
(<type 'classobj'>, <type 'object'>)
```

What's the `classobj`? And what's its difference with `object`?

### ADD 1

Maybe I am a bit dizzy today... But I guess the `classobj` just means `class a`, right? So the above output just says the method resolution order is first `class a` then `type object`.

Comment: In Python 2.7, the type of a reference to a class that does not inherit from `object` is the type `classobj`.  Example:  `class A:pass; print(type(A))` gives `<type 'classobj'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that in Python 2.x, the syntax:

```
class XXX:
    # whatever
```

will yield an "old style" class. You can read more about "old style" vs "new style" classes in [the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), on [this doc page](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) and in the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)

Then, in your case, you're not asking for the mro of class `a` but for the mro of the type of class `a` (which is what `type(a)` returns), in this case the `classobj` type. But you shouldn't worry about old-style classes, `classobj` etc unless you have to maintain or deal with legacy code.  For the record, most of Python's standard OO features (including `super()`, descriptors etc) won't work properly on old-style classes, so don't use them, and don't try to understand stuff pertaining to the "new" (well, about 10 years old by now ) object model using old-style classes...

TL;DR: you want:

```
class A(object):
    # this is a new-style class
```

> Maybe I am a bit dizzy today... But I guess the classobj just means class a, right?

Wrong. `classobj` is a kind of a special type which serves as metaclass for old-style classes. The metaclass being the class of class (since classes are objects, they are instances of a class).

> So the above output just says the method resolution order is first class a then type object.

No, it says that the mro for the `classobj` type is first `classobj` then `object`.

If you want the mro of class `a` then just ask for it - and then you'll find out why you shouldn't assess new-style features on old-style classes:

```
>>> class a: pass
... 
>>> a.__mro__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class a has no attribute '__mro__'
```

Now compare with a new-style class:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> Foo.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```